# SWT-приложение не запускается под Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, eclipse, gtk, swt

Пытаюсь портировать десктопное `SWT`-приложение на `Ubuntu`. Загрузил `Eclipse Neon (6.4.2)` для Ubuntu и `swt-4.6.2-gtk-linux-x86_64.zip`, настрроил путь к библиотеке в `project build path`, чтобы он указывал на `swt.jar` из загруженного zip-файла.
`Eclipse` работает нормально, приложение компилируется, но падает при попытке выполнить следующую строку кода:

```
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
```

Это самый первый вызов SWT в программе.
Eclipse пишет на консоль такой сообщение:

```
(SWT:3351): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplayManager'
(SWT:3351): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
(SWT:3351): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
(SWT:3351): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
(SWT:3351): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
(SWT:3351): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
(SWT:3351): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
(SWT:3351): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplay'
(SWT:3351): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
(SWT:3351): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_type > 0' failed
(SWT:3351): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
(SWT:3351): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f729ae932b7, pid=3351, tid=0x00007f72e24aa700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_111-b14) (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x4e2b7]  gdk_display_open+0x57
#
```

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Под `Windows` приложение работает нормально. 
Странно, но собранное под `Windows` приложение (в Jar со всеми нужными версиями SWT и jar-in-jar loader'ом) дважды запустилось на Ubuntu (не вполне нормально, но это естественно - нужна некоторая адаптация конкретно под GTK), а третий и последующие разы - такое же падение с таким же сообщением. 
Перезагрузка Ubuntu и `SWT_GTK3=0` ничего не меняют. 
В чем может быть причина? Куда примерно хотя бы рыть? (я в линуксах  совершенный новичок). 
PS `Ubuntu` работает в `Hiper-V` под `W2008`, если это может иметь отношение к делу ...

Comment: Неверное gtk не той системы. Это же линух. Нельзя скачать какой попало zip и надеяться, что всё заработает, как это происходит в виндовсе. Только пакеты для конкретного дистрибутива.

Comment: @Sergey, сам эклипс-то работает, значит, swt c этим конкретным gtk работает. A у них (на сайте эклипса) swt для линукса только один - без вариантов. Я подозреваю, что нужно где-то какие-то пути прописать, или переменные окружения, но где и что?

Comment: Попробуйте до запуска вашей программы в командной строке указать `export SWT_GTK3=0`, затем следующей строкой в этом же терминале запустите вашу программу. Может также зависеть от версии JVM, ранее были баги в некоторых версиях. Попробуйте с OpenJDK.

Comment: @IgorKudryashov спасибо! при запуске из jar в том же терминале, где `export SWT_GTK3=0` - программа запускается, и запускается из-под eclipse, если eclipse запущен командной строкой из того же терминала. Это для меня сейчас главное - дальше дело отладки.  Пока все равно непонятно - 1) разве export действует не на всю систему? 2) как бы это автоматизировать, чтобы не грузить такими проблемами будущих пользователей?